# Android studio crashing after Intent hit

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-intent

I just want to ask you why Intenting activity makes my system crashed? 
I've created two layout, one of them named "MainActivity" and the other one named "Login". So in main activity there is a button, I just want to pop the Login activity after hitting that button. Because I want to view the list view I've been created to see if its right or wrong. The problem here is whenever I hit the button it always crashed. Somebody help me please.

#### MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        public void okay(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

#### LOGIN ###

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] grocery_categories = {"Beverages", "Bakery", "Canned Goods", "Condiments", "Dairy", "Snacks", "Frozen Foods",
                                "Meat", "Produce", "Cleaners", "Paper Goods", "Personal Care", "Others"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, grocery_categories);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String grocery = (String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(listView.getContext(),Login.class);
            listView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            //or create other intents here
        }
    });

}
```

#### MAIN ACTIVITY XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/rl_main_activity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_grocery_bckgrnd"
    android:src="@drawable/mobile_grocery"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MOBILE GROCERY"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_grocery_app"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Application"
    android:id="@+id/application"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mobile_grocery_app"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/application"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/application"
    android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/username"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:password="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/application"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/application"
    android:onClick="okay" />
```

#### LOGIN

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.admin.mobilegroceryapp.Login"
android:id="@+id/rl_login">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/login_bckgrnd"
    android:src="@drawable/login_bckgrnd"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



</ListView>
```

#### LOGCAT

```js
09-30 11:10:39.957    2019-2210/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 8890
09-30 11:10:41.812   1735-19431/? E/OMXCodec﹕ [OMX.SEC.MP3.Decoder] err = -1011
09-30 11:10:41.882    1735-6638/? E/OMXCodec﹕ [OMX.SEC.MP3.Decoder] err = -1011
09-30 11:10:41.992   1735-20195/? E/OMXCodec﹕ [OMX.SEC.MP3.Decoder] err = -1011
09-30 11:10:42.117   1735-19431/? E/MP3Extractor﹕ Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream.
09-30 11:10:42.117   1735-19431/? E/OMXCodec﹕ [OMX.SEC.MP3.Decoder] err = -1011
09-30 11:10:42.192    1735-6638/? E/OMXCodec﹕ [OMX.SEC.MP3.Decoder] err = -1011
09-30 11:10:42.262   1735-20195/? E/OMXCodec﹕ [OMX.SEC.MP3.Decoder] err = -1011
09-30 11:10:45.782  14900-14900/? E/MtpServerJNI﹕ could not open MTP driver, errno: 2
09-30 11:10:45.787  14900-14917/? E/MtpServerJNI﹕ server is null in run
09-30 11:10:45.787  14900-14917/? E/MtpServerJNI﹕ server is null in cleanup
09-30 11:11:02.912    4074-4074/? E/MtpService﹕ In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
09-30 11:11:02.912    4074-4074/? E/MtpService﹕ battPlugged Type : 2
09-30 11:11:09.957    2019-2210/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 8891
09-30 11:11:15.392  14943-14943/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
09-30 11:11:16.807  14969-14969/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.common.h.c', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.app.GmsApplication.onCreate
09-30 11:11:17.317  28048-28048/? E/AuthorizationBluetoothService﹕ Proximity feature is not enabled.
09-30 11:11:17.492  14969-14969/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.telecom.TelecomManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.wearable.service.y.a
09-30 11:11:17.712  14969-14980/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.kz.a
09-30 11:11:17.757  14969-14980/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.kz.j
09-30 11:11:17.872  14943-14943/? E/ConnectionService﹕ Failed to connect to GoogleApiClient: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
09-30 11:11:21.612  14943-15002/? E/GmsUtils﹕ Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
09-30 11:11:39.962    2019-2210/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 8892
09-30 11:11:43.047    4074-4074/? E/MtpService﹕ In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
09-30 11:11:43.047    4074-4074/? E/MtpService﹕ battPlugged Type : 2
09-30 11:11:45.397  15132-15132/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onLoadLanguage() - lang : eng, country : GBR, variant :
09-30 11:11:45.397  15132-15132/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onIsLanguageAvailable() - lang : eng, country : GBR, variant : , iResult : 1
09-30 11:11:45.397  15132-15132/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onLoadLanguage() - LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE
09-30 11:11:45.397  15132-15132/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onLoadLanguage() - lang : eng, country : GBR, variant : f01
09-30 11:11:45.687  15132-15132/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onCreate() - Samsung TTS package (released - 2012.06.14)
09-30 11:11:45.687  15132-15132/? E/﹕ Samsung TTS Engine - initialize() : Samsung TTS Engine (released - 2012.07.11)
09-30 11:11:45.687  15132-15132/? E/﹕ Samsung TTS Engine - initialize() : ro.product.manufacturer - samsung
09-30 11:11:45.697  15132-15143/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onLoadLanguage() - lang : eng, country : , variant :
09-30 11:11:45.697  15132-15143/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onIsLanguageAvailable() - lang : eng, country : , variant : , iResult : 0
09-30 11:11:45.697  15132-15143/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onLoadLanguage() - LANG_AVAILABLE
09-30 11:11:45.697  15132-15143/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onLoadLanguage() - lang : eng, country : USA, variant : f01
09-30 11:11:45.847  15132-15144/? E/Samsung TTS﹕ onIsLanguageAvailable() - lang : eng, country : , variant : , iResult : 0
09-30 11:12:09.962    2019-2210/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 8893
09-30 11:12:22.132  15191-15234/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.telephony.CellInfoCdma', referenced from method com.facebook.common.hardware.CellDiagnosticsSerializer.c
09-30 11:12:23.157    4074-4074/? E/MtpService﹕ In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
09-30 11:12:23.157    4074-4074/? E/MtpService﹕ battPlugged Type : 2
09-30 11:12:27.297  15191-15191/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.a
09-30 11:12:29.802  15191-15191/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.facebook.push.adm.ADMBroadcastReceiver', referenced from method com.facebook.push.adm.ADMPushManager.b
09-30 11:12:31.892    2019-2087/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
09-30 11:12:32.182    2019-2087/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=217, events=0x9
09-30 11:12:33.812  15191-15300/? E/fb4a(:<default>):VaultDeviceSetup﹕ setupDeviceFromServer
```

#### MANIFEST

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".Login"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
</activity>
```

Comment: your logcat not showing your indicator app, it just show other app, can you update it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public void okay(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: To debug this. I think you should create a NewActivity then you should try to move from MainActivity to NewActivity. If I work normally, the problem   maybe come from Login Activity

Comment: Sir I used to practiced intent in other project to make sure the problem here is intent. I did same program in intent, and it aint works. But before it is working (I used same code in intent)..... Somebody told me to remove the public void of login and he is right. Now, login activity has code of listview, I probably cant remove the public void because it is supporting my codes

Comment: Not yet sir! But before this intent is not my problem. I don't know why I'm facing this kind of problem now. Before, I used same code in intent and it works

Comment: Could you update your logcat when it crash with tag Android Runtime (red color) then I will easy for help again

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the crash log,there are some permissions required in your manifest file.Make sure that you have added all required permissions and actvities in manifest file.